Compare values of columns with similar names to see if they're the same
As an example, I have this df:
df <- data.frame(
  DAY.x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  DAY = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  MONTH.x = c("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", NA, NA),
  MONTH = c("JUN", "JUL", "AUG", NA, NA)
)

and I'd like a quick way to compare columns with similar names and see if they're equal. I can do it manually like this:
with(df, any(DAY.x != DAY))
with(df, any(MONTH.x != MONTH))

but is there a faster/efficient way of automating this? In this case, I want to compare columns with the '.x' suffix with their counterpart without the '.x'. Something quick like using lapply that will show the results easily and see which pairs are not equal, but having a hard time coding this logic. Thanks.

You can create two vectors with column names to compare which would return a matrix of logical values.
x_cols <- grep('.x', names(df), fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
cols <- sub('.x', '', x_cols, fixed = TRUE)
df[x_cols] != df[cols]

#     DAY.x MONTH.x
#[1,] FALSE    TRUE
#[2,] FALSE    TRUE
#[3,] FALSE    TRUE
#[4,] FALSE      NA
#[5,] FALSE      NA

You may use rowSums which will count number of TRUE in a row.
rowSums(df[x_cols] != df[cols], na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0


Thank you! In my example data frame, the corresponding pairs are in order but in my real dataset, they can be in any order but I can probably just arrange x_cols and cols so that the sequence of column names are the same, and then apply your third line logic.

Using `==` in Reduce.
> df
  DAY.x DAY MONTH.x MONTH
1     1   2       B     A
2     1   1       B     C
3     1   3       B     A
4     1   3       C     C
5     2   1       C     A
6     2   1       A     A

> sapply(c(0, 2), \(i) Reduce(`==`, df[c(1 + i, 1 + i + 1)]))
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE
[5,] FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE  TRUE


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(DAY.x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), DAY = c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), MONTH.x = c("B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "A"
), MONTH = c("A", "C", "A", "C", "A", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

